# AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'set_options' after installing dask with conda

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am using annaconda and I just installed dask using below

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dask

```
conda install -c conda-forge dask
```

I can use read_csv() and no error, however, I got this error . I am wondering if I need to install everything using

python -m pip install "dask[complete]"

will it conflict with installed dask using anacondas? Thanks

```
import dask.multiprocessing
dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)  # set processes as default

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
cnrl\users\yongnual\Data\Spyder_workplace\DTS_dashboard\pandas2_high_performance_testing.ipynb Cell 14 line 2
      1 import dask.multiprocessing
----> 2 dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)

AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'set_options'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `dask.set_options` syntax has been replaced by `dask.config.set(...)` in [2018](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/3502).

Also, can you try installing `distributed` alongside?

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge dask distributed
```